# ShowWindowCommandsOnTop not accessible in 1.0.0.0

Tags: mahapps.metro

Recently I upgraded to Mahapps 1.0.0.0 from 0.14.0.0 and I'm getting error on `ShowWindowCommandsOnTop="False"` as it is inaccessible. Where did it go?

Comment: by the way, i answered your question, but why not questioning directly to the mahapps team (per issue)

Comment: I don't know where to ask directly to Mahapps. Please tell me. That will make my life easier too!

Comment: you can do this by using the Gitter chat or creating issues before looking at the issues, if there is still a answered issue for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ShowWindowCommandsOnTop` was removed by these new properties

```
public WindowCommandsOverlayBehavior LeftWindowCommandsOverlayBehavior
public WindowCommandsOverlayBehavior RightWindowCommandsOverlayBehavior
public WindowCommandsOverlayBehavior WindowButtonCommandsOverlayBehavior
public WindowCommandsOverlayBehavior IconOverlayBehavior
```

property values are

```
Never
OverlayFlyout
OverlayHiddenTitleBar
Always
```

[0.14 release-notes](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/docs/release-notes/0.14.0.md)